# Is "swop" an acceptable variant of "swap"?

Tags: orthography

I've always spelt it with an "a". But my friend insists on spelling it with an "o". Is this an acceptable variant?

Comment: Roald Dahl says 'swop places' in Danny the Champion of the World I was very surprised - hence I'm here!

Comment: There is also 'swot', a variant spelling of 'swat'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [American English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/swap) and [British English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swap) *swop* is a variant spelling of *swap*. (See the *also **swop*** note at the top of the page.)

The copy of the NOAD I had on my Mac Mini explicitly said *swop* is a variant spelling of *swap*, and also reported *swop* as chiefly British.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that spelling.  You learn something new everyday.

Comment: I *am* British, but if I've ever seen *swop*, I'd just have assumed it was a spelling mistake. Certainly not what I'd expect from a careful (reasonably educated) writer. NOAD may well be right, but that would be odd because in general if there's a US/UK difference in spelling, the US form is more likely to be phonetic (thanks to the efforts of Webster & such).

Comment: If it's an acceptable variant, I think I'm going to start using it just to have some fun with people! :)

Comment: I remember finding "swop" in print, and later being chastised for copying that spelling. The spelling appeared in a UK children's book; I believe it was "Ging Gang Goolie, It's An Alien" by Bob Wilson.

Comment: It seems to be the prevalent spelling in Singapore as well.

Comment: @RJ Lol, I also saw it in a UK children's book; "Go to bed" by Emma Lynch.

Comment: Mari-LouA's point is a good one: this answer actually links to Oxford Dictionaries, not the OED (Oxford English Dictionary). OED is different from Oxford Dictionaries and has a separate online presence at www.oed.com, even though it's associated with the same institution.

Answer (score 3):

I know that "swop" is a variant, having seen it in manuals and help discussions like this, but I've never seen it used in real life (i.e., in US usage). Looks very UK-ish.

Comment: British people exist in real life too ;-)

Comment: Normally, the US version makes more sense phonetically in my experience.